# GRPCwebProxy and Iroha

Tags: grpc, hyperledger-iroha

I have running the IROHA node on my local ubuntu machine with docker and I am able to run all commands using docker shell.

[image: All Dockers]

I want to have JS implementation of Iroha so I have run the dockerfile for GRPC but it is not able to connect to IROHA,
error:

```
WARN[1672] [core] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {dev.localdomain:50051 dev.localdomain:50051 <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:50051: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting... system=system
[GRPC console][2]
```

Comment: 1. please provide logs in text format

Comment: 2. Did you expose ports from docker?

Comment: It was sorted out by using some ready made docker compose file for GRPC

Comment: "Some ready"? From Official docs? Please show it if you really wanna help. ;)

Comment: ok bro sure, let me answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved GrpcWebProxy by making some changes in already provided solution, now you can see it here:

https://github.com/AqeelKazmi/IrohaDockerServices